# Converting a int pointer to a void pointer and back to use the value in another function?

Tags: c

I would like to convert a int pointer to a void pointer and pass that void pointer to a function and then back to an int pointer to use that value in another function.

```
void main(){
    int newSize = size;
    void *newSizePtr = &newSize;
    someFunc(newSizePtr);
}

void someFunc(void *newSizePtr){
    int actualValue = *((int *) newSizePtr);
}
```

Is this the right way to convert a int ptr to a void ptr and then back to use the value?

i am unable to dynamically allocate memory to the pointer itself because of restrictions with my program that i cannot use malloc. i.e.

```
int *newSize = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

which is why i did it this way.

i also need to pass in a void* argument because in my program i am using pthread_create(). This function requires me to pass in an argument of a void* to the function which is why i casted it to a void* and then back when i needed to use it

Comment: Yes. That will work.

Comment: I agree with @John3136. However, since you are defining the function `someFunc()`, is there a reason why you would not define it to have an `int *` as its parameter or, indeed, why you would not just pass an `int` parameter? Either approach would make the type conversion unnecessary. Every type conversion is potentially risky because it prevents the compiler from catching type bugs in your code, so it is preferable to use as few as possible.

Comment: Thanks guys, the reason i need to use a void* because i am using pthread_create().
This function requires me to pass in an argument of a void* to the function which is why i casted it to a void* and then back when i needed to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion you are doing is explicitly allowed by the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  Section 6.3.2.3p1 regarding pointer conversions states:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any
>   object type.  A pointer toa ny object  type  may  be  converted  to  a
>   pointer  to `void` and  back  again;  the  result  shall compare equal
>   to the original pointer.

It's also not necessary to explictily cast to or from a `void *`.  So you can do something like this:

```
void someFunc(void *newSizePtr){
    int *actualValuePtr = newSizePtr;
}

int main(){
    int newSize = size;
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, someFunc, &newSize);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i added the reason why i needed to use void* because of pthread_create() and one of its argument is that it needs a void* to be passed in instead of a int*

Comment: @WilsonM You can freely pass an `int *` to a function expecting a `void *` as in my sample code.

Comment: I must be doing something else wrong then because when i pass in either a void* or a int* the argument gets corrupted when the new thread is created.
For example, passing in a int* with an value of 4, when debugging the value becomes something crazy like 1409485739.
I must be corrupting memory somehow, all good I will continue to debug.

Comment: @WilsonM you should post a separate question for that issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

void someFunc(void*);

int main() {

    int size = 4;

    int newSize = size;

    void* newSizePtr = &newSize;

    someFunc(newSizePtr);

    // void* -> int*, before using
    int* newSize = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));

}

void someFunc(void* newSizePtr) {

    int actualValue = *((int*)newSizePtr);

    printf("%d", actualValue);

}
```

Yes you can cast void* to int*, and int* to void *,

Because, void * is 'generic' pointer.

malloc returns generic pointer (void*) because malloc does not know what 'type' of return you need.

So, you need to convert to the type you need.

(In the above code, you need to convert to void* -> int*)

For more information about usage of generic pointer, below link may help you

https://codexpart.com/what-is-generic-pointer-difference-between-generic-pointer-and-void-pointer/

Comment: Thanks, that malloc part looks right to me but unfortunately i cannot use it in my program because i am using sbrk()